# Simplified Dictionary using comprehensions

Tags: python, dictionary-comprehension

everyone i'd like to know a way to simplify the following code with a dictcomprehension:

```
import random

vowel = "aeiou"
consonants = "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz"
hand = {}

for i in range(numVowels):
        x = VOWELS[random.randrange(0,len(VOWELS))]
        hand[x] = hand.get(x, 0) + 1
        
for i in range(numVowels, n):    
        x = CONSONANTS[random.randrange(0,len(CONSONANTS))]
        hand[x] = hand.get(x, 0) + 1
```

Comment: What is the code supposed to do?

Comment: use `random.choices` to compute the list in one go, and then `collections.Counter` to make the dict. but the answer really is that you can't do it with comprehension

Answer (score 1):

No. As far as I know, `list` and `dict` comprehensions don't work when you want to get the value of elements in the middle of the comprehension. This can cause unexpected outputs.

The `for` loop changes the contents of the `dict` with each iteration, while a `dict` comprehension first creates the entire `dict`, and then assigns it to the var.

Here's an example with a list comprehension:

```
# for loop
>>> l = [1] * 20
>>> for i in range(1, 20):
...     l[i] = l[i - 1] + l[i]
...
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]

# list comprehension
>>> l = [1] * 20
>>> l = [ l[i - 1] + l[1] for i in range(1, 20) ]
>>> l
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2
```

And a dict comprehension

```
# for loop
>>> s = "abcdefghij"
>>> d = {}
>>> for i in range(10):
...     d[s[i]] = d.get(s[i - 1], 0) + 1
...
>>> d
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5, 'f': 6, 'g': 7, 'h': 8, 'i': 9, 'j': 10}


# dict comprehension
>>> s = "abcdefghij"
>>> d = {}
>>> d = {s[i]: d.get(s[i - 1], 0) + 1 for i in range(10)}
>>> d
{'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'c': 1, 'd': 1, 'e': 1, 'f': 1, 'g': 1, 'h': 1, 'i': 1, 'j': 1}
```